# Oracle error:Throws Not a Valid Month error in debugger but runs fine in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

This query runs fine in Oracle SQL developer but throws an error in the code while debugging. It throws an error: Not a valid month. Why the same query would run fine in SQL developer but break in the code?

Request Date is Date datatype 01-JAN-13 Format
Request Time is Char datatype 10:11:12 Format

```
SELECT 
TO_TIMESTAMP((TASKTB.REQUESTDATE || TASKTB.REQUESTTIME), 'DD.MM.YY:HH24:MI:SS') "Scheduled Time", 
FROM
 TASKTB.TaskType, 
WHERE ( TASKTB.TASKTYPE = LISTTB.VALUE )
```

Comment: Why do you store a single timestamp in two varchar columns? That's one of the biggest mistakes you can make. Fix your datamodel and the error goes away.

Comment: That can't be fixed right now I need to figure out an alternate way to fix this query. Thanks

Comment: As long as you don't fix the *real* problem, you are going to hit that problem over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
SELECT 
TO_TIMESTAMP((to_char(TASKTB.REQUESTDATE,'DD.MM.YY') ||':'|| TASKTB.REQUESTTIME), 'DD.MM.YY:HH24:MI:SS') "Scheduled Time", 
FROM
 TASKTB.TaskType, 
WHERE ( TASKTB.TASKTYPE = LISTTB.VALUE ) ;
```

if REQUESTDATE is a date dataype as you say.. then you need to perform an explicit 'to_char' to the desired format.